# How do I add more text in this box?

Tags: html, css

I have this rounded box with text in it. It's going to have a download button in it. I don't know how to add more text/links in it though, only one.

```css
p {
  font-size: 34px;
}

#rcorners1 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #D3D3D3;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 345px;
}
```

```html
<p style="font-size:67px;padding-right:13px;" id="rcorners1">Zinexium</p>
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit, you want to have text & links in your `<p>`  tag ?

Comment: @Aladin Yes, but not in the same <p> tag. I want them in the grey box, but I don't know how to put them in the grey box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would wrapping items in a div help?

```css
p {
  font-size: 34px;
}

#rcorners1 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #D3D3D3;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 345px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rcorners1">
<p style="font-size:67px;padding-right:13px;">Zinexium</p>
<p style="font-size:32px;padding-right:13px;">More text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I also think it's better to use div tag for container.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap elements you would like to be in the grey box in a `div`, I added a class `grey-box`. Don't set a fixed width or height to the box unless necessary  as this could cause an overflow which may not be desired. If you don't set a fixed height or width, the grey box will grow or shrink depending on the sizing of the elements within.

```css
p {
  font-size: 34px;
}


.grey-box{
  padding: 20px;
  background: #D3D3D3;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grey-box">

<p style="font-size:67px;padding-right:13px;">Zinexium</p>
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the height and width of the box ,decrease padding and font size . Then you can increase the number of letters than before.